# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <body> cannot appear as a child of <div> in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use `<body>` tag but getting following warning:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <body> cannot appear as a child of <div>.
body
Body
App index.js:1
    e index.js:1
    React 16
        printWarning
        error
        validateDOMNesting
        createInstance
        completeWork
        completeUnitOfWork
        performUnitOfWork
        workLoopSync
        renderRootSync
        performSyncWorkOnRoot
        scheduleUpdateOnFiber
        updateContainer
        legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer
        unbatchedUpdates
        legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer
        render
    js index.js:9
    js main.chunk.js:1941
    Webpack 7
        __webpack_require__
        fn
        1
        __webpack_require__
        checkDeferredModules
        webpackJsonpCallback
        <anonymous>
```

Following are my App.js and Body.js files:

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Header/Navbar/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
import Body from "./components/Body/Body";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Body />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Body.js**

```
import React from "react";
import HomeScreen from "../../screens/HomeScreen/HomeScreen";

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <body>
      <HomeScreen />
    </body>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

I am using React Version: ^17.0.2

Comment: Well it seems to be exactly what the error message says. You can't render a `<body/>` tag inside a `<div/>` tag. How are you rendering the `<App/>`?

Comment: This question is related to how HTML works and OP needs to read the manual. Body is not a random tag to throw in the middle of your app like a div or span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`body` must be [the second element of an `HTML` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body). It can't be the child element of anything else. So maybe change how you approach things:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Content />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

And:

```
const Content = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <HomeScreen />
    </main>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, you can't use `<body>` inside a `<div>` tag (or any other). The body of the application is already defined in the `index.html` file.

```html
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

You could place your body component inside a `<div>` tag that you use as a body for content.

```js
import React from "react";
import HomeScreen from "../../screens/HomeScreen/HomeScreen";

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <HomeScreen />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

Or you could use a fragment.

```js
import React from "react";
import HomeScreen from "../../screens/HomeScreen/HomeScreen";

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <HomeScreen />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

Or simply:

```js
import React from "react";
import HomeScreen from "../../screens/HomeScreen/HomeScreen";

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <HomeScreen />
    </>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the body tag wrapper from the body.jsx, it causes the body tag to render insider a div which is the reason for the error, body tag should always be the child of the HTML tag only.

All the elements you add in the App.js file will render inside the body tag unless you change either the element to render inside in the index.js or assign the id root to any other element in index.html

```
import React from "react";
import HomeScreen from "../../screens/HomeScreen/HomeScreen";

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <HomeScreen />
    </>
  );
};

export default Body;
```